# Science Fiction Book where Earth is a technocracy ruled from Paris

Tags: story-identification

I read this book in the 1960s. It was set in the (then) future when the Earth was ruled from Paris by scientists - a technocracy. The hero obtains an illegal device which works on the principle that walls have memory and can store events that have happened in the room. He takes the device to a ruined London and in a house there learns what had happened to the Earth. Back in 1999 the political crisis was such that scientists decided to take over. To make their point they fired a nuclear device at the moon destroying it.

It may have begun with aliens landing on an ice covered world and finding a recording of what had happened.

Can anyone name the book and its author?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: So, you're saying that *walls have ears*?

Answer (score 6):

***[When the Moon Died](http://andrewdarlington.blogspot.com/2013/01/1950s-sf-novel-when-moon-died-by.html)***, with the author's name given on the cover as **Richard Savage**. This was actually a pen name of a British author named Ivan Roe. According to one reviewer, this was Roe's *only* venture into science fiction, although he also used "Richard Savage" for other types of fiction. User14111 found [an entry for this novel](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?299987) on ISFDB, after I failed to find one, but I've settled for linking the title in my opening line to a blog post, written by an "Andrew Darlington," which reviews this book while discussing its plot in *considerable* detail.

["Richard Savage"](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/savage_richard) has faded into obscurity, but does receive a few lines in an online resource called "The Encyclopedia of Science Fiction" (or SFE for short, I gather).

Here's a copy of the cover scan which the blogger used. Perhaps it will look familiar?

[image]

Now I'll compare points from your post to points from the blog review, and you'll see why I feel sure of my ground when I say that you and Darlington are speaking of the same novel. I'll try it this way: Each time I insert a number, I am about to quote from your post. If I quote something else right after that, it will be a passage from Darlington's blog which covers the same ground.

1. You said:

> I read this book in the 1960s.

The paperback edition that had that cover was released in 1963. (A previous edition, apparently hardcover, had come out in 1955.)

2. You said:

> It was set in the (then) future when the Earth was ruled from Paris by scientists - a technocracy.

Darlington says:

> For his protagonists, the real future-action is located thousands of
> years later, with people living in an enlightened World Technocracy, a
> scientific dictatorship administered through eight semi-autonomous
> regional committees. Back when I first read it, Savage’s vision of
> cities seemed a viable future scenario to me. The region formerly
> known as France consists of a series of 1,500 sky-scraping cities,
> each with a five-million population, yet separated by bush and wild
> forest-land, connected only by air-freight. It’s a curiously engaging
> image. Paris is the Quiet City of Glass where Karsh’s usual workday as
> a ‘humble electronics Tech’ at the Media Video
> Communications-Propaganda System lasts no longer than four-hours.

3. You said:

> The hero obtains an illegal device which works on the principle that walls have memory and can store events that have happened in the
> room.

Darlington says that Karsh is the main hero of the story, and describes some of his activities:

> Deciphering its principles – that light leaves its retrievable residue
> on old buildings, Karsh secretly constructs his own monitor as a
> ‘dangerous telescope’ into the past, not always understanding what he
> sees.

4. You said:

> He takes the device to a ruined London and in a house there learns what had happened to the Earth.

Darlington doesn't seem to agree that London was where Karsh first learned the ancient history of what happened to destroy the moon and change the world, but does agree that he makes a trip over to London and beyond for the purpose of using his secret device to capture certain scenes regarding a friend's disappearance.

> Stalked by sinister investigating Inspector Blok, he’s informed that
> Drew died in ‘Psycho-Refuge 87’. And travels to neglected London
> intent on uncovering the truth, to find the city a dilapidated
> European backwater gradually being reabsorbed into the encroaching
> bush-lands of Middlesex and the forests of Essex. Somewhere beyond its
> sad decay, possibly Oxford, he uses his device to observe the more
> recent past. Drew had not died. He was drowned by two thuggish Refuge
> warders.

5. You said:

> Back in 1999 the political crisis was such that scientists decided to take over. To make their point they fired a nuclear device at the
> moon destroying it.

Darlington says, describing the backstory that led to the world which Karsh inhabits:

> Then, as the year 2000 approaches, a secret cabal of scientists band
> together and step in to halt the superpower
> mutually-assured-destruction, demonstrating their power by using an
> ‘N’-bomb to destroy the Moon, then emerging after the ‘ten days of
> terror’ as the Moon dies, to assume global control and establish the
> Interim Rule. What is left of the Moon forms an arc of luminous
> fragments subsequent generations call the ‘supernova’.

6. You said:

> It may have begun with aliens landing on an ice covered world and
> finding a recording of what had happened.

Darlington says, describing the framing sequence of the novel:

> Here, aliens from ‘Universe Five’ seek the remains of human cities
> that lie frozen beneath the ice that sheaths the dead planet once
> called Earth. By chance they happen upon a functioning tape-recording
> made by ‘Karsh’, through which the long-deceased narrator answers some
> of their questions.

So it looks like your memory is serving you quite well regarding major plot points after all these years!

I poked around on Amazon to see if any old copies of the book are for sale, in case you decide that you must reread the whole thing instead of being satisfied with Andrew Darlington's review to refresh your memory of some of the fine points. It turns out that yes, [there are some for sale.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LP1XX0C) If you follow that link and click on the bit that says "See all 4 formats and editions," you'll find that someone seems to be selling a used copy of the paperback for seven dollars (plus shipping costs, I take it), and someone else is willing to sell another copy for eight dollars (again, plus shipping). A copy of the hardcover edition, on the other hand, would cost a whopping **$36.85** as it now stands. (Again, plus shipping!) It appears that no one has taken the trouble to convert the text of this book into an e-book which could be purchased online and downloaded to read via Kindle.

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?Richard%20Savage

Comment: @user14111 -- I've got a question. Did you add that "Richard Savage" entry yourself, or did you just dig it up after I had somehow missed it? I'm willing to edit it into my answer, but I'd like to know whether it had been there on ISFDB all along.

Comment: Maybe it was added recently. Not by me, I don't edit ISFDB. Is there a view the edit history, like with Wikipedia?

Comment: I just looked it up to see if ISFDB had really missed it, and there it was.